# Is it possible to check who and when removed column from particular sharepoint 2010 list?

Tags: 2010

Is it possible to check who and when removed column from particular sharepoint 2010 list?

How to do it if it is possible?

[UPDATE 1] Auditing is disabled. Any alternatives?

Comment: Without Auditing it's not possible I think. Since you have no other way of seeing the details in modifications made

Answer (score 1):

You can view the details in your Audit Reports for Content Activity.

1-Go to Site Settings at the site collection root level.

2-Under the "**site collection administration**" section, open the "**Audit log reports**"

3- under the "**content activity reports**" section, click on the "**content type and list modifications**". *This report shows all events that modified content types and lists*.

Comment: Audit log is disabled, any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

### Using Audit

You can use the audit log reports provided with SharePoint  to view the list modifications.

> NOTE: Auditing must be enabled to use audit log reports in SharePoint
>   Server 2013. By default, auditing is enabled in SharePoint Online.
>   Find more information about enabling auditing in [Configure audit
>   settings for a site collection](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/redir/HA102866204.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739).

### Using Change log

SSOM [SPChangeQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeQuery%28v=office.15%29.aspx) defines a query that is performed against the change log in SharePoint.

Supported APIs: SSOM, CSOM, REST

Example

How to retrieve changes for Field objects in List via CSOM:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);   
var query = new SP.ChangeQuery(true, true);
query.set_item(false);
query.set_field(true);

var changes = list.getChanges(query);
context.load(changes);
context.executeQueryAsync(
     function(){
         for(var i = 0; i < changes.get_count(); i++ )
         {
             var change = changes.getItemAtIndex(i);
             console.log(change.get_time()); //print change time

         }
     },
     function(sender,args){
         console.log(args.get_message());
     }
);
```

Comment: Audit log is disabled, any alternatives?

Comment: How about  ChangeQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using a feature receiver. You will need the field deleting method.
When this fires, you can then write to another list, or prevent the user from deleting the field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisteventreceiver.fielddeleting.aspx

Comment: I have a feeling the deletion has already happend